# Using seq() to subset a group of 100 rows every nth row

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset where I want to look at a set of 100 rows every 450 rows. I know I can do something similar using seq():

```
df <- df[seq(1, nrow(df-1000), 450),]
```

but this returns only 1 row (the 450th, 900th, etc). Is there something I can add to this to return 100 rows?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `outer(seq(0, nrow(df-1000), 450), 1:100, '+')` for generating the indices.

Comment: `1:100 + rep(seq(0, nrow(df), by=450), each=100)`

Comment: Thank you @user20650, I have used your suggestion and it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @user20650, this has been solved with the use of rep() in the following code:

```
df <- df[1:100 + rep(seq(0, nrow(df), by=450), each=100),]
```